# How to synchronize a body with multiple joints in Unity network/Photon Unity network?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, photon, unity-networking

This is what I have tried.

I have made a 2D body that has child objects connected with joints and I added the photonView component to the body and dragged the child gameObject transforms there. The problem is that it's quite inaccurate and when I set motor speeds it lags and the position isn't the same on the other players screen.

This is probably asked really badly,but all I want to know is how can I correctly synchronize a body with multiple child gameObjects attached with joints.

Also I haven't tried using RPC calls at the moment, but I have a feeling it will make the game lag :/

Answer (score 0):

One problem might be that you effectively setup two different code pieces that both affect the body and it's children: The physics does and now remote players also get updates from the net - with a delay that will corrupt your physical world.

You could disable the physics on the objects which you don't control. Make those kinematic and then update the object only with what you get via the network. It will lag but that's up to you to compensate and hide (and another topic).

You might want to aggregate the updates sent for "your" object with the updates of the children. So you get a snapshot of the whole character/object when it arrives.